# Can you log out a user from multiple domains ? (expire all sessions)

Tags: force.com-sites, customer-portal, authentication, session

Our customer portal is available in multiple languages, all of them have their own domain and allow the user to switch languages.

Currently, when a user logs out, we take the user to https://company.support.com/secur/logout.jsp, which works fine for the current domain/language but not if the user had authenticated under another domain such as https://company.support.de and then switches to the English website, they will continue to be authenticated in the German version.

Is there a way to expire all the sessions for a given user?